# Can we change a list which is inside a tuple in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

Example:

```
 a = (1,2,[3,4,5],6)
```

Can we make changes and make tuple `a` to give output as

```
>> (1,2,[3,0,5],6)?
```

Comment: If you get a reference to the list then you can mutate that in place, eg: `a[2][:] = [3, 0, 5]` but not quite sure that's actually what you're asking... what's your use case here?

Comment: `a[2][1] = 0` Will do what you want. To answer your actual question, Yes, we can change a list inside a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes like this:

```
a=(1,2,[3,4,5],6)
a[2][1] = 0
print(a)
```

What this does is gets the third element of the tuple wich is the list then gives the new data to the second element in the list then prints out the whole tuple with the new data in the list.
I believe this is what you want to do please tell me if it isnt thanks.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: The question does not ask for this, I revoke my downgrade, but either change the answer or delete it.

Comment: I believe I have changed it correctly now

Comment: yes, now the answer is correct, but the downgrade does not belong to me, I think asker did it. I will upvote

Comment: While adding the `print(a[2])` line may help your understanding of the question, without any comments this part of the answer is confusing.

Comment: made corrections to it and removed the print statement thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, like this:

```
a=(1,2,[3,4,5],6) 
a[2][1]=0
print(a)
```

This takes the third element of a, which is the list and modifies each element in the list separately.

Comment: Why are you changing `a[2][0]` and `a[2][2]`? You only need to change `a[2][1]`?

Comment: @ZackTurner yes, but when I wrote my answer, your code was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You might do it using `pop` and `insert` methods of that `list`

```
a = (1,2,[3,4,5],6)
a[2].pop(1)
a[2].insert(1, 0)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, [3, 0, 5], 6)
```

These methods acts in place, `pop` removes element at index `1` (indices are starting from `0`), `insert` inserts before element at index `1` value `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
a=(1,2,[3,4,5],6) 
b = a[2]
b[1]=0
a
```

Output:     `(1, 2, [3, 0, 5], 6)`

Answer (score -1):

Python tuples are immutable. The only solution to change the content is to create a new tuple. Here note that your tuple element at index 2 stores an array, which is mutable by reference so you can mutate the array but not assigning a new array.

In other words:

```
t = (1, 2, [3, 4], 5)

# New tuple:
t = (1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 5) # or
t = (t[0], t[1], [3, 4, 5], t[3]) # to copy values

# Mutate the array:
t[2].append(5)
```

In your case:

```
a = (1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6)
# Mutate the array
a[2][1] = 0
```

Comment: Triples are immutable but objects inside a tuple are not.

Comment: Only reference types are mutable, you can't assign a new value to a tuple element, if `t = (1, 2, 3)` you cannot do `t[0] += 1` or `t[0] = 2`. And for reference types like arrays you can mutate the array but not the reference: if `t = (0, [1, 2], 3)` you cannot do `t[1] = [4, 5]`.